# Images inside div keep moving

Tags: html

```
<div style="banner" top:0; align="center" position: absolute; z-index: 1; visibility: show;>
<img src="banner.jpg" /></div>
<div style="buttons" align="center" top:200; left:85; position: fixed; z-index: 1; visibility: show;>
<img src="homebutton.jpg"/><img src="aboutbutton.jpg" /><img src="missionbutton.jpg" /><img src="contactbutton.jpg" /><img src="pricingbutton.jpg" /></div>
<div style="pics" align="center" top:370; position: fixed; z-index: 1; visibility: show;>
<img src="inrepair.jpg" /><img src="homeoffice.jpg" /><img src="onsite.jpg" /></div>
<div style="pics2" align="center" top=711; position: fixed; z-index: 1; visibility: show;>
<img src="computers.jpg" /><img src="networking.jpg" alt="Networking"/><img src="games.jpg"/></div>
```

The combined width of my images are 1024px. As soon as I drop the browser size below 1024px width all the images other than the banner start to stack on top of each other. I want them to just hide what cannot be shown like the banner is already doing. What can I do to fix this? I'm sure theres a very easy solution, but I'm pretty bad at html.

Comment: Your markup is very broken for starters. Is this page online to view? All that `position:fixed` doesn't look very healthy either.

Comment: CSS and html, I only put the part of the code thats causing me problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a "container", element with fixed width of 1024px that will contain all of these images

```
<div style="width: 1024px">
    all of the images goes here
</div>
```

just note that if you what to keep the page without a horizontal scroll the `<div>` should be less than 1024 because of the vertical scroll